# Any way to optimize/properly refine this <50 line script?

Tags: python, optimization, nmap

I'm still learning python, and one of the first projects I decided to dive into was something to sort through large nmap logs, pull out the OPEN ports, and dump them to a separate text file in IP:Port format.  It works, but is there a better way to write this?  Here's what I ended up with:

```
import sys
import string

"""
Written 6/24/2011 to pull out OPEN ports of an nmap proxy scan
Command:
nmap 218.9-255.0-255.0-255 -p 8080,3128,1080 -M 50 -oG PLog3.txt
"""
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'Usage: python proxy.py <input file> <output file>'
    print 'nmap 218.1-255.0-255.0-255 -p 8080,3128,1080 -M 50 -oG PLog.txt'
    print 'Example: python ./proxy.py PLog.txt proxies.txt'
    sys.exit(1)

r = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
o = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

pat80 = '80/open/'
pat8080 = '8080/open'
pat3128 = '3128/open'

for curline in r.xreadlines():
    sift = string.split(curline, ' ')
    ip = sift[1]

if curline.find(pat3128) >= 0:
    curport = '3128'

elif curline.find(pat8080) >= 0:
    curport = '8080'

elif curline.find(pat80) >= 0:
    curport = '80'

else:
    curport = '100'
    pass


if (curport == '3128') or (curport == '8080') or (curport == '80'):
    o.write(ip + ':' + curport + '\n')
    print ip + ':' + curport

else:
    pass
```

Comment: isn't the indentation a little off? it feels `for curline in r.xreadlines():` should be one level above all those ifs

Comment: Perhaps you mean to post this to [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I assume the '100' value is a bogus value meant to avoid the final `if` condition, and doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: instead of `if curline.find(pat3128) >= 0` use `if pat3128 in curline`

Comment: @leon, I apologize, that was my fault in porting over and manually adding the indentation.  You are correct.  @Karl, the 'if' condition was bogus.  Was going to use a null value but had the line leftover during a revision, just reused the number.  @ignacio, thanks for the link, I'll be using that for sure in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over a file like this. There is no need to use `xreadlines()`. `with` makes sure the file is closed when `r` goes out of scope

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as r:
    for curline in r:
        sift = string.split(curline, ' ')
        ip = sift[1]

    ...
```

Looking in a tuple is neater than the chain of `or`

```
if curport in ('3128', '8080', '80'):
```

Comment: Thank you.  The reasons I used xreadlines was because it was recommended for larger files.  Some of my scans turned out to have 50,000+ lines, so I figured that was a 'large' file.

Comment: @ken, You're welcome. xreadlines was the correct way to do it in the old days before file objects were iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Since I seem to remember using python to parse nmap output files was one of my first python applications, I can make a couple of recommendations:
1) If you'd like to learn XML parsing and python, using the alternate XML format of nmap would be advised.  This has the advantage that the XML output is less like to change in small but script breaking ways unlike the plain text output.  (Basically, matching on string fields is great for a quick hack but is almost guaranteed to bite you down the road, as I found out when nmap was updated and they slightly changed the format of one of the columns I was parsing on... also think I got bit when we upgraded one of the Windows boxes and some of the text in the OS or services fields matched something I was matching on.  If you're interested in going down this path, I can see if I have my nmap parser using xpath lying around

2) If you want to stick with text output and regexp, I'd suggest learning about grouping.
Specifically, rather than creating custom patterns for each port, you can define a group and check that out instead.

```
import re
r = re.compile("(/d+)/open") # match one or more digits followed by /open
mm = r.match(line) #mm will either be None or a match result object, if mm is not None, you can do mm.groups()[0] to get the port #.
```

Comment: Meant to give an example for 2... here goes:

Comment: -1 for breathing "XML" and "Python" in the same sentence. Horror!

Comment: @Karl Knechtel kindly propose a better way to robustly handle nmap's default outputs in the face of potential changes

Comment: I like the use of regex here, and it never crossed my mind.  These makes the whole definition of proxy ports based on the nmap scan that's run at command line.  I'll be using this tidbit for the next revision of the script!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import string

"""
Written 6/24/2011 to pull out OPEN ports of an nmap proxy scan
Command:
nmap 218.9-255.0-255.0-255 -p 8080,3128,1080 -M 50 -oG PLog3.txt
"""

def get_port(line):
    port_mapping = {
        '80/open/': '80', # Is the backslash special here?
        # If they're really all supposed to have the same form,
        # then we can simplify more.
        '8080/open': '8080',
        '3128/open': '3128'
    }
    for pattern, port in port_mapping:
        if pattern in line: return port
    return None # this would be implied otherwise,
    # but "explicit is better than implicit"
    # and this function intends to return a value.


def main(in_name, out_name):
    with file(in_name, 'r') as in_file:
        ips = (get_port(line.split(' ')[1]) for line in in_file)
        with file(out_name, 'w') as out_file:
            for ip in ips:
                if ip == None: continue
                output = '%s:%s' % (ip, curport)
                out_file.write(output + '\n')
                print output


def usage():
    print 'Usage: python proxy.py <input file> <output file>'
    print 'nmap 218.1-255.0-255.0-255 -p 8080,3128,1080 -M 50 -oG PLog.txt'
    print 'Example: python ./proxy.py PLog.txt proxies.txt'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3: usage()
    else: main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Further to the comments in the code: Do we really care only about these specific ports, or about any port that happens to be listed in the file?

Comment: for my use it was explicitly these ports.  I will be revising this to work with any port as specified in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Check out argparse for handling the arguments.

Split into functions.

Use the **main** construct.

Look at the csv module. You can set the delimiter to a space.

Look again at the re expression. You can do it with one re expression where it is an 'or' of the different patterns.